# tmux C-i key kills bash completment?

Tags: bash, vim, tmux

Now I'm a new user of vim-tmux-navigator. But when I set key bindings like below, tab key doesn't complement commands in my bash which is opened by tmux.
When I comment out *bind -n C-i..* line, complementing commands work again.

Is default C-i binding related some important functions?

```
 unbind-key C-b  
 set-option -g prefix C-q 
 #bint C-j send-prefix
 # Vim Tmux Navigator
 # https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator
 bind -n C-y run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_title}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-y) || tmux select-pane -L"
 bind -n C-u run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_title}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-u) || tmux select-pane -D"
 bind -n C-i run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_title}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-i) || tmux select-pane -U"
 bind -n C-o run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_title}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-o) || tmux select-pane -R"

 set-window-option -g utf8 on
 set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
 set-window-option -g automatic-rename off 
 #color
 set-option -g status-bg blue
 set-option -g status-fg yellow
 set-option -g history-limit 100000
```

Answer (score 5):

There are some keys in the terminal that get translated to `ctrl` equivalents. Here's a couple of them:

- `Tab` is `Ctrl-i`
- `Enter` is `Ctrl-m`
- `Backspace` is `Ctrl-h`

The shell (bash) never really gets the `Tab` keystroke (same for `Enter` and `Backspace`). It always get the `ctrl` equivalent.

Long story short: `Ctrl-i` and `Tab` are equivalents. If you bind `Ctrl-i` the same binding will be applied to `Tab` key.

Comment: Oh, I never knew that! Are there any ways to disable ctr-i at mac's default terminal?